# Binary replace in a range in Unix

Tags: replace, binaryfiles

I need to search and replace a byte string inside a specific range in a binary file.

> Search into mytest.pcap from byte 1000 to 2000
>
> Replace x93\x33\x59\x05\x00 with x93\x33\x59\x00\x0

Thanks,
Riccardo

---

My approach:

```
sed 's/\x93\x33\x59\x05\x00/\x93\x33\x59\x00\x00/g' mytest.pcap > mytest_mod.pcap
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` line you used seems good, so I guess what remains is the range. Unless you have somewhat strict performance requirement, I believe this could work:

```
(head -c1000 mytest.pcap;
 tail -c+1001 mytest.pcap | head -c1000 | sed 's/.../.../g';
 tail -c+2001 mytest.pcap) > mytest_mod.pcap
```

*Update*:

If the performance is an issue, I think there's no other choice than to write a single-purpose program (maybe `perl` would allow a "one-liner", but that's not my area). In python it could look like this:

```
import sys
import re

sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read(1000))
range = sys.stdin.read(1000)
sys.stdout.write(re.sub('\x93\x33\x59\x05\x00', '\x93\x33\x59\x00\x00', range))
while True:
    buf = sys.stdin.read()
    if buf:
        sys.stdout.write(buf)
    else:
        break
```

Note that it strongly relies on that `read(1000)` would really read those 1000 bytes; for this size, I believe it is quite safe assumption.

Save the snippet to a file named like `subst_range.py`, then run `python subst_range.py < mytest.pcap > mytest_mod.pcap`.

Comment: This works! But the file is 50MB, so with your approach there are performance problems..

Comment: I'm trying to write down the code in perl. On your opinion, @volverine, is it possible to modify directly the mytest.pcap file?

Comment: Yes, it is; only I'm not sure it would help you with anything, perhaps the disk space. But unless you are using very unusual device, 50MB is not an issue, or is it?

Comment: The problem is that I need to find and replace multiple values and the file is big....